# IIS Api redirect rule

Tags: asp.net, regex, api, iis, web-config

I need some help with a redirect regex in my web.config. I have a website UI and an App UI which hit the same serverside API but I'm decoupling the urls that get called from either for future-proofing the app against API updates.

This is what I have so far in my web.config and it works for redirecting api.mywebsite.com to mywebsite.com, but how do I write the regex to add the version at the end so that http://api.mywebsite.com/v1/ gets redirected to http://www.mywebsite.com ?

```
<rules>
          <rule name="Remove WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(api\.)(.*)$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://dev.blahblah.org.au{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
    </rules>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the **(.*)** capture the **/v1/**? Or am I missing something?

Comment: With your settings it should already be the case. You have `url="^(.*)$"` that match your `v1/` and `input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(api\.)(.*)$"` matching `api.mywebsite.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<rule name="Remove WWW" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(api\.)(.*)$" />
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/v(\d+)/(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost{PATH_INFO}?v={C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: This is bang on what we need. In our case though, the only difference is using action type="Rewrite" to do a transfer rather than a redirect.